# The characterization of asymptotic dimension

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, asymptotics, metric-geometry

Let $X$ be a metric space. The following conditions are equivalent

(a) ${\rm asdim}\ X = n$

(b) $n$ is the smallest integer such that for every $R > 0$ there exists $n + 1 $ families $U_i\ i=0,1,2,\ldots,n$, and $S > 0$ such that each $U_i$ is $R$-disjoint, $S$-bounded and the families $U_i$ cover $X$

I cannot understand the proof of theorem.

Comment: Could you give a little context to this question?  For example, where did you find the theorem, and what about the proof do you not understand?

Comment: I  read the text 'Large scale geometry',and the theorem in finite decomposition comlexity. (b)→(a) is clear by the definition of asymptotic dimension , but (a)→(b) is not clear.By (a), there exists uniformly bounded cover with R-multiplicity n + 1 , but I cannot construct the familiies satisfied (b)

Comment: more precisely, I cannnot construct the families satisfied R-disjoint

Comment: @MaiSasaki: There is a proof in http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0507570v2.pdf (Thm 1) but it goes through another two equivalent conditions. I would also be interested in a more direct proof of $(a)\Rightarrow(b)$.